# How many sequences we can make from 4 digits, such that they don't have more than one zero.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My attempt: I tried to count the number of ways that the four digits don't have one zero, which is $9^4$, then count the number of ways that they have exactly one zero, I got confused a little on how to count them, but I split this into cases where the zero appears on the first digit, I have $9^3$ ways, and shifted it to the left one by one and added all of them up and got $4*9^3$. so my answer is $9^4+4*9^3$ 
 
Would appreciate if someone can approve my work, or if there's other easier ways to solve this. 
 Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct assuming the problem asks for number of $4$-strings.

To make it concrete, the case of one zero appearing can be handled as : choosing one of the four spots for zero, and filling rest three spots with non-zero digits.
$$\binom{4}{1}\cdot9^3$$

Comment: Thankss, finally I get a question correct!! :)